Vpkg + gRpc не видит собственные хэдеры
Установленный vcpkg + gRpc
   PS C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\vcpkg> vcpkg list grpc
    grpc:x64-windows                                  1.68.2              gRPC is a modern, open source, high-performance ...
    grpc[codegen]:x64-windows                                             Build code generator machinery
    PS C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\vcpkg> vcpkg list
    abseil:x64-windows                                20240722.0          Abseil is an open-source collection of C++ libra...
    c-ares:x64-windows                                1.34.3              A C library for asynchronous DNS requests
    grpc:x64-windows                                  1.68.2              gRPC is a modern, open source, high-performance ...
    grpc[codegen]:x64-windows                                             Build code generator machinery
    openssl:x64-windows                               3.4.0               OpenSSL is an open source project that provides ...
    protobuf:x64-windows                              5.29.1              Google's language-neutral, platform-neutral, ext...
    re2:x64-windows                                   2024-07-02          RE2 is a fast, safe, thread-friendly alternative...
    utf8-range:x64-windows                            5.29.1              Fast UTF-8 validation with Range algorithm (NEON...
    vcpkg-cmake-config:x64-windows                    2024-05-23
    vcpkg-cmake-get-vars:x64-windows                  2024-09-22
    vcpkg-cmake:x64-windows                           2024-04-23
    zlib:x64-windows                                  1.3.1               A compression library

Пример CMake файла
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)

project(server LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Protobuf ProtobufTools Grpc GrpcTools)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(Protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(Threads)

add_library(protoServer ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/proto/api.proto)
set_target_properties(protoServer PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
target_link_libraries(protoServer gRPC::grpc++)
protobuf_generate(TARGET protoServer LANGUAGE cpp OUT_VAR GENERATED_PROTO_FILES PROTOC_OUT_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
target_include_directories(protoServer PUBLIC ${GENERATED_PROTOBUF_DIR})

protobuf_generate(
TARGET protoServer
LANGUAGE grpc
GENERATE_EXTENSIONS .grpc.pb.h .grpc.pb.cc
PLUGIN "protoc-gen-grpc=\$<TARGET_FILE:gRPC::grpc_cpp_plugin>"
IMPORT_DIRS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/proto
PROTO ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/proto/api.proto
PROTOC_OUT_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/proto")

qt_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
  Server_global.h
  server.cpp
  server.h
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core
    Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Protobuf
    Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Grpc
    gRPC::grpc++
    protoServer
)

target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE SERVER_LIBRARY)


vcpkg.json
{
  "dependencies": [
    "grpc",
    "protobuf"
  ]
}

При компиляции пишет ошибку, не может найти #include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>. Если напрямую указать путь из vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\grpcpp - то уже сам заголовочный файл ругается что не может внутри себя найти #include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
Что не так? Что я упустил? Система Win11 VS 2022 Community

Все верно пишет, в скрипте cmake нет указания, где искать заголовочные файлы grpc.
